# When source is empty how to show offline message in exoplayer

Tags: android, kotlin, exoplayer

I need to catch errors thrown by exoplayer when there is no input or bad stream. If there is no input activity opening showing player with controls nothing is displaying. when there is no input hls source I need to show the alert dialogue that Streaming is offline. How to achieve this. Please help.

````
class playlive : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var player: SimpleExoPlayer? = null
    private var playerView: PlayerView? = null
    private var playWhenReady = true

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_playlive)
        playerView = findViewById(R.id.player_view)


        play()

    }

private fun play(){

        val trackSelector = DefaultTrackSelector()
        trackSelector.setParameters(trackSelector.buildUponParameters().setMaxVideoSizeSd())
        player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this, trackSelector)

    playerView!!.player = player
    val dataSourceFactory = DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory(Util.getUserAgent(this, "app-name"))
    val uri = Uri.parse("http://localhost:1935/live/mystream/index.m3u8")
    val hlsMediaSource = HlsMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(uri)

    player!!.playWhenReady = playWhenReady
    player!!.prepare(hlsMediaSource)

}
    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        releasePlayer()

    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        releasePlayer()
        resumePlayer()
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        releasePlayer()

    }

    private fun releasePlayer(){
        player?.release()
    }

    private fun resumePlayer(){
        play()
    }

    }```
````

Comment: how about showing a textview for offline message on top of the ExoPlayerView

Comment: Can you show me how to do with the code above? I think first I need to catch the error and show it using alertdialogue.